# Node.js find method works weird

Tags: javascript, node.js, find

I have this Node.js method for GET queries

```
app.get('/:tableName', function(req, res) {

    var schema = require('./schema/' + req.param('tableName'));

    var q = unescape(Object.keys(req.query)[0]);
    console.log('query:' + q);

    schema.find(q, function(err, result) { 

        if (err) { 

            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({status: 'failure'});
        } 

        if (result) {
            res.json(result); 
        } else {

            res.json({status: 'not found'});
        }
    });
});
```

The strage, that if I call it i.e. whit this input .. (it is exactly the value of `var q`)

```
{
  "remoteID" : "80E75ED5-B696-446E-9AA7-9B170350D7E6"
}
```

.. I get back 3 items **but non of them match the condition**, basically it **returns all the items in table**.

```
[{"lastName":"K","remoteID":"D5DC51C1-C415-4073-A647-1D41BB47D03E","password":"p","firstName":"J","email":"xxx","airline":"73C02335-C019-419E-BCC7-C87537F38492","userName":"J","_id":"5353b639889a61000038848c","__v":0},

{"lastName":"asd","remoteID":"C471495C-C218-4440-BA81-7BD37CBB5605","password":"wn831","firstName":"asd","email":"asd@asd.hu","airline":"73C02335-C019-419E-BCC7-C87537F38492","userName":"ASA","_id":"5353b639889a610000388491","__v":0},

{"remoteID":"5A0D51DE-DCD0-4E3E-9D97-7CAD066DB68A","userName":"R","password":"R","_id":"5353b639889a610000388492","__v":0}]
```

Comment: What is this `schema` object, looks like some database connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One important line was missing:

```
var jq = JSON.parse(q);
schema.find(jq, function(err, result) {
```

find() method requires not string but JSON object.